# ExtractValue in TYPO3

Tags: php, mysql, sql, typo3

I want to update my website with using the doctrine of TYPO3.
But in my command where, i want to use an ExtractValue, and doctrine understand this parameters like a field, and not like a function of sql.

This is my code :

```
$statement = $queryBuilder
   ->addSelectLiteral(
   )
   ...

   ->where(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('ExtractValue(n.flexform, \'//field[@index="erasmusStatus"]/value[@index="vDEF"]\')', 1);
   )
```

And the result in SQL :

```
... WHERE (`'ExtractValue(n`.`flexform, \'//field[@index=\"erasmus\"]/value[@index=\"vDEF\"]\')'` = 1))
```

You can see that SQL takes 'ExtractValue(n' like a field.

But i want :

```
...WHERE ('ExtractValue(`n`.`flexform`, \'//field[@index=\"erasmus\"]/value[@index=\"vDEF\"]\')' = 1))
```

Do you know a QueryBuilder or expression to do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what about making it a string?

```
... 
->where(
    $queryBuilder->expr()
                 ->eq('ExtractValue(`n.flexform`,
                                    //field[@index="erasmusStatus"]/value[@index="vDEF"]\')', 
                                    1);
                     )
```

Comment: It's the same result

Comment: and if you insert the splitted name as you want it (`\`n\`.\`flexform\``)?

Comment: Same too ! I tryed to inversed ExtractValue(...) and 1, it's works, ExtractValue is take like function by SQL, but '1' is takes like field.

Comment: It's okay, I find the solution

Answer (score 0):

It's work with this :

```
... 
->where(
    str_replace('`',"'", $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(1, 'ExtractValue(`n.flexform`,//field[@index="erasmusStatus"]/value[@index="vDEF"]\')');
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plain string in where condition:

```
->where(
     'ExtractValue(n.flexform, \'//field[@index="erasmusStatus"]/value[@index="vDEF"]\') = 1'
   )
```

This is possible in more methods, for example andX:

```
    ->where(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
            'FROM_UNIXTIME(tstamp) = ' . $queryBuilder->quote('2018-12-13 20:34:19'),
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('uid', 6)
            )
        )
```